# Export Superscript text to worddoc from HTML

Tags: asp.net, regex, export, superscript, export-to-word

In my asp.net website I have a HTML page which contains some words with Superscript, for example the HTML representation is as below...

```
ABC<sup>def</sup>
```

when it is rendered in browser it appears like this : ABC<sup>def</sup>

I have a export feature which export the HTML document to a word document. When I am exporting it is being exported as  `ABC<sup>def</sup>`  in the worddoc.

I have been trying to do it using some kind of regex `html = html.Replace("<sup>", "\"");`
but that doesn't help.

Can anybody please help me how would I make it appear as ABC<sup>def</sup> in my word document too using asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but I've been trying to do the same thing in reverse. The problem is with how Word formats and defines its super and subscripts.

There are no tags that Word used to define super and subscripts, it uses relative positioning and font-size declarations to generate symbols that look like super and subscripts.

Unfortunately there is no reliable regex to turn Word's positioning into super/subscripts, and there is no way to regex a document with those tags to make Word recognize them.